# How can I keep trailing content from overlapping my tab content?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, tabs

i developed a web page that uses only CSS to resolve a Tab pattern of design. To it's objective there is no issue, and works; but it has a couple of bugs i'd like to fix, and can't seem to find the way to do it.

Would be good if the solution would be compatible with a IE 7, 8 or 9 (since my current pattern only works on Edge, Chrome and Firefox).

The problem occurs when i have elements below the containing DIV, and the content inside overlaps it. It seems that the DIV container does not "resize" as the tabs change.

Here's an example of how the page is:

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <style>
      .tabs{display:block;list-style:none;position:relative;padding:0;border-bottom:4px solid #475b7e;}
      .tabs li{margin:0;display:inline-block;font-weight:bold;cursor:auto;border:none;max-width:100px;vertical-align:top;}
      .tabs li .tab{display:none;}
      .tabs li i{font-weight:normal;}
      .tabs li [for^=tab]{background-color:#bcc7d8;color:#314362;display:block;position:relative;padding:0 4px 0 4px;margin:0;line-height:18px;}
      .tabs li [for^=tab]:hover{background-color:#ffffff;color:#475b7e;}
      .tabs li .tab:checked + [for^=tab]{background-color:#314362;color:#ffffff;}
      .tabs li .tab:checked + [for^=tab]:hover{background-color:#475b7e;color:#ffffff;}
      .tabs li .tab:checked ~ [class=tabcontainer]{display:block;position:absolute;left:0;width:100%;}
      .tabs li .tabcontainer{display:none;padding:6px 4px 20px 4px;font-weight:normal;}
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <p>Below is a DIV that i would like to grow with the UL list; and also be able to see the text on the next P mark (below the DIV); and more, i would like to be able to use this on IE 7 as well, at least IE 9.</p>
     <div class="container">
      <ul class="tabs">
       <li>
        <input type="radio" class="tab" name="tab" id="tab_first" checked="checked" /><label for="tab_first">First</label>
        <div class="tabcontainer">Content of First, single line</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <input type="radio" class="tab" name="tab" id="tab_second" /><label for="tab_second">Second</label>
        <div class="tabcontainer">Content of Second<br />2 Lines now</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <input type="radio" class="tab" name="tab" id="tab_third" /><label for="tab_third">Third</label>
        <div class="tabcontainer">Content of Third<br /><br />3 lines, second is empty</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <input type="radio" class="tab" name="tab" id="tab_forth" /><label for="tab_forth">Forth</label>
        <div class="tabcontainer">Content of Forth, (just because) 1 line again</div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <input type="radio" class="tab" name="tab" id="tab_fifth" /><label for="tab_fifth">Fifth</label>
        <div class="tabcontainer">Content of Fifth<br />Another line, but even more<br /></br /><br />Now done</div>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <p>Text i would like to see</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

One other thing is, would be OK to use javascript on it (since i already use jQuery-UI on the site) but i can't change the "UL" structure to use the jQuery-UI Tabs model.

Please help!

Comment: This might help you https://onextrapixel.com/creating-content-tabs-with-pure-css/

Comment: That is almost the same structure i used; even the CSS is almost the same - nice - i'll test it though, because i didn't where it would not overlap the next elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute positioning presents a challenge, which is why CSS-only tabs and jQuery tabs have different markup structure. You could write jQuery to modify the markup before applying jQuery's tabs component:

```
// create a contents element below the list
$('.container').append('<div class="tabs-content"></div>');

// loop through each list item
$('ul.tabs li').each(function() {

    // move contents to div below list and give each an index-based ID
    $(this).find('.tabcontainer')
           .appendTo('.tabs-content')
           .attr('id', 'tab' + $(this).index());

    // strip markup from list items and build anchors targeting the appropriate ID
    $(this).html('<a href="#tab' + $(this).index() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</a>' );

});

// initialize jQuery-UI tabs
$('.container').tabs();
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4vaub85c/5)**

Comment: seems to produce the result ... will it affect something else? i'll try first, but liked very much

Comment: Only if you have other elements with the same classes in your page. You'd have to be more specific with selectors if that's the case.

Comment: not what i meant, sorry; i mean on postback, server recognition of elements when the page call's back and things like that; also, "before" and "after" elements work on IE 7 ou 9? i'm checking and testing first - then i'll mark your answer and use it

Comment: well ... it "worked", i'll keep this as a solution but i had to make a few changes, like the ".container" doen't always exist (on every page) and the result is a little "unformated" - the tab header is been created extremely large in height - all adjustments i'm doing based on this, so thank you @isherwood